# Range defined by values contained in cells

Tags: vba, excel, range

I'm struggling with a code.

So here is what a need:

Everyday I need to define and copy a range, which begins in a cell that contains the word "patrimonio" and ends in a cell that contains the word "total". So the range needs to select everything between those two words. For example: I have a worksheet that cell "A3" contains the word "patrimonio" and cell "A20" contains the word "total", so the range will be "A3:A20", but in other day the word "total" can be at the cell "A14", and the word "patrimonio" will be at cell "A5", so the range will be "A5:A14".

How can I write a code to define the range based on what word is in the cell?

Comment: Did you already tried something? If yes please post your code.

Comment: Do you want VBA or formula could also work for you? You can get this using formulas also...

Answer (score 0):

Consider:

```
Sub FindDemo()
    Dim alpha As Range, beta As Range, rCopy As Range
    Dim Dest As Range

    Set Dest = Range("Z100")
    Set alpha = Cells.Find(What:="patrimonio", After:=Cells(1, 1))
    Set beta = Cells.Find(What:="Total", After:=alpha)
    Set rCopy = Range(alpha, beta)

    rCopy.Copy Dest
End Sub
```

Once the block is found, it is copied to **Z100**

Modify the destination to meet your needs.